# Telemetry for local network

Tags: telemetry

I am trying to run a local network and post telemetry.

I am running it with this command

```
SKIP_WASM_BUILD= cargo run -- \
    --base-path data/node1 \
    --chain local \
    --alice \
    --telemetry-url 'wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/0 0' \
    --name validator-alice \
    --validator
```

However , I get the following error in the console:

> 2022-03-17 23:46:42 ❌ Error while dialing
> /dns/telemetry.polkadot.io/tcp/443/x-parity-wss/%2Fsubmit%2F0: Custom
> { kind: Other, error: Other(A(Handshake("server rejected handshake;
> status code = 404"))) }

I would appreciate any assistance in understanding what I am doing wrong

Comment: It might be badly parsed, the `SKIP_WASM_BUILD=` directive has nothing / is assigned to the the run command here? I suggest instead using `cargo buid -r` , the debud build will _not_ work well event in testing only.

Comment: Does it work if you omit the `SKIP_WASM_BUILD= `?

Comment: you might also enjoy this tutorial to further your understanding: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/node-metrics/

Comment: It looks like the status code is 404. Try to spin up a basic node with telemetry like Dan suggested and see if that connects...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/private-network/ has a good overview of how to do this correctly, including this command as reference for a [node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) *built* with `cargo build -r`:

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/alice \
--chain local \
--alice \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator
```

Looks like you have and extra `0` in the command you listed.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the previous answer, the `0` in `"wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0` is the telemetry verbosity level. If you want to run your own local version of [`substrate-telemetry`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-telemetry) you would use `ws://localhost:8000/submit 0`.